# Typescript JSDoc ...Rest type syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsdoc

Got a problem when beginning with typescript on an existing large react/redux application.

As a proof of concept, I've converted one of my react files to a .ts file. I'm trying to add types using JSDoc to the imported JS files to tell Typescript what params are available (instead of just declaring the module as any in a .d.ts file).

My issue is with a "rest" parameter that's used in a react functional component to pass props through to a another react component. In the below example, Typescript is identifying the prop "id" as not existing.

.tsx file:

```
import ReactFunction from 'wherever_it_is/react_function';

//inside another react component
<ReactFunction
    prop1="something"
    id="unique"
/>
```

wherever_it_is/react_function.jsx file:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} ReactFunctionProps
 * @prop {boolean} prop1 - descriptive text
 * @prop {...any} ...otherProps - pass through props
 */

/**
 * descriptive comment about ReactFunction
 *
 * @param {ReactFunctionProps} props
 * @return {import("@types/react").JSX.Element}
 */
export default function ReactFunction({
    prop1,
    ...otherProps
}) {
    return (
        <OtherThing
            {...otherProps}
        />
    );
}
```

Using Typescript 4.1.3.

Anyone know the correct syntax to Typescript JSDoc a "...rest" operator? As far as I can tell, I am using the correct syntax from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html where the rest operator is mentioned.

Any other suggestions? (other than `declare module wherever_it_is/react_function;` which I'm aware will import the module as `any` -- trying not to resort to that yet)

Comment: Is there a reason to start with JSDoc instead of adding Typescript types? You could have just started to add JSDoc along with some JS tooling if you really want that.

Comment: No reason other than new to adding Typescript to an existing project and feeling my way around. I think I found a list of increasingly strict ways of using Typescript and using JSDoc was higher up than creating actual Typescript types. Seems like a much more natural fit to create Typescript types rather than learning all of the specialized JSDoc syntax as well as Typescript.

Comment: JSDoc is great for additional documentation with Typescript to give more description to a function or parameter, but since it is completely separate, the syntax for types will be completely different and redundant once you add more detailed type information directly in Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the @typedef way, where you constructs new Props type and then just intersect it with React.HTMLAttributes like in pure Typescript syntax:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} TextInputProps
 * @property {string} [className]
 * @property {string} label
 */

/**
 * @param {TextInputProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>} props
 */
function TextInput({
    className = '',
    label = '',
    ...props
}) {...}
```

That way seems a little weird, because you need to mix Typescript types and functionality with JSdoc syntax, but it worked by me.

You can also see square brackets for `classname` param - you can mark that param as optional.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Just a note that this doesn't support inline import (e.g.: `@param {MyTypeDef & import("somelib").LibProps} props`). Instead, you need to import the `LibProps` normally, then you can use it as `@param {MyTypeDef & LibProps} props`

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a .d.ts file and define the type in Typescript syntax.

wherever_it_is/react_function.d.ts:

```
export default function ReactFunction({
    prop1,
    ...otherProps 
}: {
    [x: string]: any;
    prop1: any;
}): JSX.Element;
```

While this technically doesn't answer the question, it is a way forward. My suspicion is that the ...rest use case isn't supported by the JSDoc typing method.